# Typescript `Array.join` literal return type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types, type-inference

I have an array like:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b'] as const;
// type: readonly ["a", "b"]
```

Now I want to join the strings in the array:

```js
const joined = arr.join('');
// type: string
```

My goal is to write a function that joins strings in an array and returns them as a literal string type (`"ab"`).

Does someone know *if* this is even possible? I think it should be, since all the type information needed is given. I don't expect a full solution to the problem - maybe just a hint for further research would be great.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You just need to define a function and move all the required operations inside the function body, then return the result.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis But how to get the function *typed* as desired? I'm thinking it might involve a recursive variadic tuple type. Easily doable if the function itself is recursive, but to use `.join` and recurse only in the type is a step beyond.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think the task involved is actually much simpler than what you describe.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis Could well be, but I'm not seeing it at the moment - the type functionality doesn't look built into `.join`, which may mean you have to implement it manually..? Feel free to post an answer if you have an idea.

Comment: Something like this? https://tsplay.dev/NnK8om

Comment: I'm too tired to write [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnK8om) up as an answer, so consider it your hint. Feel free to self-answer with what you learn from this. The type inference can also be improved with TS4.7 by using [`extends` constraints on `infer` type variables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables)

Comment: @spender thank you that was excacly what I was looking for! I will see if I can improve the inference and post the answer if I am succesfull - but your answer definetely resolves my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = ['a', 'b'] as const;

type JoinStrings<T extends readonly string[]> = T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer R]
  ? `${F}${JoinStrings<R>}`
  : '';

const joinArray = <T extends readonly string[]>(arr: T): JoinStrings<T> => arr.join('') as JoinStrings<T>;
const joined = joinArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const joinStrings = <T extends readonly string[]>(arr: T): `${T[number]}` => arr.join('') as `${T[number]}`;

const arr = ['a', 'b'] as const;
const joined = joinStrings(arr); // type: "ab"
```

try this.
By using `as ${T[number]}`, you are telling TypeScript that the return value of `arr.join('')` should be treated as a literal string type based on the elements in the array.

Comment: the returned type in your example is `"a" | "b"`, not `"ab"`

Answer (score -1):

```
const joinedString = (arr as string[]).join('');
console.log(joinedString); // Output: 'ab'
```

This should work.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about how to join an array of compile-time constants and have the returned *type* be the literal `'ab'` and not `string`.